# pass multiple parameters using $.ajax to an MVC method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use:

```
$.ajax({url:'controller/method ?startDate=' +  startDate + '& endDate=' + endDate});
```

In the controller I have a method like this:

```
public PartialView GetChartDate(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate){}
```

When I do this I end up passing null for endDate to the MVC method even though it has value. How do I pass multiple params to the MVC method?

Ideas and suggestions greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you actually cut-and-pasted your code, there's a space between the ampersand and the variable.

```
$.ajax({url:'controller/method ?startDate=' + startDate + '& endDate=' + endDate});
                                                            ^
```

Not sure if that is what does it, but check it out.

Answer (score 12):

Don't create query string on your own. Rely on jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/controller/method',
     data: { startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}
     // ...
});
```

Comment: This is probably the better method - less likely to make typos this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/xyz/xyz",
            data: "param1=" + value+ "&param2=" + value,

        });
```

i think it works, because i am using it and working with this